WiFi disappeared after upgrade from ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS
I recently updated my dell xps 9310 from the dell's official release (20.04 LTS) to the newest 24.04 LTS, but after the upgrade the WiFi, bluetooth and sound features disappeared. In particular:

WiFi is not listed anymore in the settings menù
bluetooth is listed, but cannot be enabled
the only output audio device listed is the Dummy Output

I tried to list lshw -C network and it stops scanning the Network Interfaces without giving any output, then I listed the PCI devices with lspci to find the network controller, which is Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20).
Furthermore, connecting the laptop to the wired network I found that the nameservers disappeared from resolv.conf and also all the saved ssh connection disappeared from ssh.conf.
However, after sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade the issue is still present and no additional driver were found from the Software & Updates page, and it says that "No proprietary drivers are in use".
Any idea? Does it happen to anybody else?

Me too! My wireless disappeared too.

Check and see if you're running Linux kernel 6.5. My Intel wifi driver (iwlwifi) completely stopped working => the driver is buggy.
Try to revert back to a v5 kernel with grub and see if your wifi comes back.

Run the following commands and restart. It works for me
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade

